# Is there any possibility to make clicker that choses randomly an option and click on it?

Tags: javascript, python

So, I want to make a clicker that can choose random options from dropdown on a website. I have tried to do some in Javascript, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there even any possibility? If yes, which programming language would be the best to do this?

Comment: yes, there is, i wont explain the code, but what i will do is using findelements to get all the options from dropdown, then create a method that returns a random number or use an inbuilt library to do so, then do something like driver.findelementsbyid("yourid").get(randomnumber).click()

Comment: but what language should I use?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the intro tour.  Your question is out of scope in several respects.

Comment: you can use any language, all do the same, i recommend you to do a selenium tutorial first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are severous ways.
Here one  in javascript :

- Get the number of option
- Read how to generate random number between 0 and this number. Take a look there : 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/random
- Then now find a way to associate each number to the corresponding option. For example, in your html code, give to options an id of 1,2,3,4 etc ...
- Get your element in javascript. Take a look there : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp
- now click on it ! https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click